# Remove grub and keep only Ubuntu

Tags: grub2

I used to use Windows and Ubuntu on my pc. But I'm no longer a Windows user, now only Ubuntu. I tried to instal Ubuntu over the Windows, but grub still installed and asks every boot which system should it start. Theres a way to remove completly and start straight on Ubuntu?

Comment: Nope. GRUB is still needed to load Ubuntu, irrespective of what else you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Grub is still needed, it tells the OS what kernel to load. You can hide Grub by changing its settings and make it so that it immediately boots to ubuntu and never shows you any options. An easy program to do this with is [grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) and then going through settings to make it so that the autoboot is ubuntu and the time delay is 0.

Comment: Please do not suggest grub-customizer unless its necessary. OPs needs can be easily achieved without using grub-customizer. Just by changing `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` in `/etc/default/grub` .